# ListView selected items add other ListView

Tags: c#

How to add ListView selected items in other ListView?

Example project:
[ExpTreeLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422497/ExpTreeLib-Version-Explorer-like-Navigation-and)

Put this form ListView2 and add lv.selectedItems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to add the items

```
ListView list = new ListView();
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

// add them
list.Items.Add(item);
```

This would be enough, now you can use a simple loop for each element to add it to that list.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView.SelectedItems) {
   // create a new list, or use currently present list
   // add each item to it using .Add() method.
}
```